# What is the best software to track events/issues/incidents from start to finish whilst exporting periodic updates?

Tags: car

I have 2 reports that I need to issue every week providing an update of all the new incidents that happened the week just gone and to also provide updates on all the incidents that have been brought forward that have not been closed out. Currently this is being performed in Microsoft Word and being manually updated and sent out as a PDF each week. This is getting unacceptable as the list of new incidents grows with us getting more cars in the fleet and there are multiple people involved in adding updates to the Word Documents making it difficult to identify who has added what.

What the software needs to achieve:

- Be able to present all the incidents in an export with the attached format and potentially in a columned format that is easily searchable e.g Date - Car ID - Type - Incident Title - Incident Notes.
- Need to be able to have the colouring of the update show orange for still under investigation and green for item closed this week.
- Need to be able to clear off items that have been closed (that have not been closed this week)
- Needs to export into PDF across multiple pages - ideally sending straight to an email inbox without having to save PDF first.

Flexibility or areas happy to compromise on:

- Cost - I am not exclusively looking at free options and would be more than happy to consider paid options
- I am happy to compromise having the data in a tabulated format as opposed to free text for the Date - Car ID - Type - Incident Title - Incident Notes
- Tracking who has added what is not immediately urgent, but would be a nice to have
  [image]